# How MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA operates?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

can anyone explain for me how does MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA operates?
this is how i used it in my app

```
String[] projection = {MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA};
```

i searched online but still couldn't find good explanation for it,
please if anyone can explain it for me in simple terms i would appreciate it

Comment: Seem a very general question, because Android abstract how it's operate. It's just extract data from the media, wathever the media is. So, it's operate in different way for different media. It's store MediaStore store metadata about indexed media content. MediaStore.MediaColumns store common data from different datatype/media (Audio/Video/Image,...) to have a easier access to theses informations.
So, do you want to know : how Android store this information? how Android retrieve theses informations on indexes media? how android retrieves informations on a media when added on indexes media?

Comment: @A.H thanks for your explanation, in my app, am using it to store image chosen by the user, i would like to know how does it store it. What will be in the projection Array?, thanks again

Comment: https://books.google.fr/books?id=QP7VvnhDOOsC&pg=PA443&lpg=PA443&dq=MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA&source=bl&ots=Z_uYM1PguH&sig=YssiqkwzZyB7DksoXTyiKzHVVAE&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjVq-Cgy4XKAhWJqxoKHSxdB3AQ6AEIYzAJ#v=onepage&q=MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA&f=false can help you to understand.

Comment: @A.H okay, am looking into it